# New Window Positioning in Electron

Tags: position, window, electron

I need to know how to open new windows which is offset a little by the current window position (first window will be opened in the center)

My codes are as follows:

```
// index.js

const {app,BrowserWindow,Menu,MenuItem,dialog}=require('electron');

function window_open(path){
  win = new BrowserWindow({show: false})
  win.loadURL(path);
  win.once('ready-to-show', () => {win.show()})
}


let win

app.on('ready',event=>{
  'use strict';
  window_open(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`)
});
```

This opens the initial window in the center.  I am also passing this function in the new window command (cmd+n)

```
{
  label: 'File',
  submenu: [
    {label: 'New Window', accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+N', click: () => (
     window_open(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`))
},
```

The code works fine, except that every window is positioned the same, in the center.  I would like each new windows to be offset a little.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I learned that I need these two things:

1. [BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow()](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#browserwindowgetfocusedwindow)
2. [win.getPosition()](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#wingetposition)

Combining with @pergy's response, I got the following code which finds the focused window if there is any and offsets a new window from its position, otherwise creates a new window in the center:

```js
let win = null;
function window_open(path) {
  const opts = { show: false };
  if (BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow()) {
    current_win = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow();
    const pos = current_win.getPosition();
    Object.assign(opts, {
      x: pos[0] + 22,
      y: pos[1] + 22,
    });
  };
  win = new BrowserWindow(opts);
  win.loadURL(path);
  win.once('ready-to-show', () => { win.show() });
};

app.once('ready', event => {
  window_open(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);
});
```

This does what I asked for in my original question, so I have decided to post this.  However, I do feel that it is slow in spawning the new windows, so I won't mark this as an answer to see if there are faster approaches to this.

---

**Update:**
I have found out that waiting on `'ready-to-show'` is what makes it slow, as it waits for the ready state.  I have accepted this as the answer as I feel that the speed issue is dependent to the content and not the browser.  Feel free to add comments on this as I am still open ears.

Answer (score 3):

You can define the window's position in constructor option `x` and `y`. The currently active window's position can be retrieved with `getPosition()`, so you can define offset for the new window from that.

See this dummy app for example:

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

let win = null
app.once('ready', () => {
  const openWindow = () => {
    const opts = {
      show: false
    }
    if (win) {
      const pos = win.getPosition()
      Object.assign(opts, {
        x: pos[0] + 10,
        y: pos[1] + 10
      })
    }
    win = new BrowserWindow(opts)
    win.loadURL('http://google.com')
    let thisWin = win
    win.once('ready-to-show', () => {
      thisWin.show()
    })
  }
  setInterval(openWindow, 5000)
})
```

Comment: I have removed the answered mark for now, because I learned that there is an offset lag if I click cmd+n really fast.  For example, if I click cmd+n really fast 3 times, then the offset will be 22x3 = 66.  Kind of confused on why this is even possible.

Comment: @JosephKim yeah, i can reproduce it too by decreasing interval. What i see is that `opts` is correct, but not every window opens

Comment: I've edited my answer to call show on the correct win instance (haven't tested though).

Comment: It seems to open each iteration, but it's as if it's buffering the load.   If I select the previously opened window, it is ignoring the currently active window and continues offsetting from the last opened window position.